# ETF holding shares in itself

Tags: etf

Why would an ETF hold shares in itself and what are the implications?

[image: ETF portfolio]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lindsell Train Investment Trust](http://www.lindselltrain.com/~/media/Files/L/Lindsell-Train/Attachments/Latest/LTIT_Latest.pdf) could be different than the "Lindsell Train Limited", the company that runs the fund and thus you are mixing apples and oranges here since the bank isn't a listed stock.

Comment: Good catch, JB!